# How can i make food have a more desirable smell?

Tags: smell, aroma

I am cooking a wrap with avocado, chicken and vegetables such as carrots, cucumber, capsicum, red onion etc.

However, once I make these, they don't have any smells to it. So I was wondering how do I make it smell better?

More spices on the chicken?

Comment: What spices are you using now and are you serving the wrap hot or cold?

Comment: @Stephie i'm only using garlic powder at the moment on the chicken. The wrap is served at room temperature (not chilled)

Answer (score 2):

In general, cold and room temperature food need more seasonning as the volatile compounds that make up odor (what you smell) will not be as, erm, volatile.

There is not set rule on how much to add; experience plays a big role here.

When cooking your ingredients, in your case, chicken, you can add a **little bit more** seasoning, herbs, spices, salt.

Just be careful not to add too much as some herbs and spices can become bitter in larger quantity.

For your specific case, I would add cilantro and lime to the wraps.

(In my taste, ) I would skip the carrots and cucumber as they are not that flavorful and add water to the end product; make a side salad with them.

Comment: What type of seasoning? I know you mentioned herbs and spices but which ones? (what type of aroma do they bring?)

Comment: Whatever seasoning you like in respect to the original recipe, in that case, it looks "tex-mex" so, maybe cumin, maybe chipotle ...

Answer (score 2):

Your ingredients look ok.  I am suspicious that you are not cooking at all; the chicken is already cooked.  You are assembling ingredients.  Good lunch making - I do it all the time.

You have an idea of how a wrap should smell because you have eaten ones that have a smell you like.

A way to accomplish that in a predictable way is **sauce.**    There are seasoned sauces of all sorts that have great smells.  Get a wrap you like and see if you can figure out what the sauce is that makes it smell good, then buy some and use it.  Toss your ingredients in the sauce so they get saucy then assemble.

Comment: Thanks! I feel like if i add a sauce it will clash with the avocado because at the moment the filling is pretty creamy already

Comment: Avocado sauce is guacamole.   What do you like in your guacamole?

Comment: What in the guacamole would make it have a good smell?